# How to do Redis tree and optimize it + Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, tree, redis

I need to have cached data that will be used by several node.js workers. Below, there is hierarchy of that data, it's 3 layer deep :

[image: Redis data structure]

Each category has the same subcategories, and both of them are of fixed size. 
Each "Data" contains 4 fields, one of which is an unique ID. There will be quite a lot of "Data" inserting and deleting.

What is the best way to implement such database in Redis? Hash sets for cat+subcat since I have fixed amount of them, and hash set also for Data becouse of that unique ID every field has?

Thanks!

Comment: How will you be accessing the data? Will you be scanning through all members of a category, or only accessing nodes directly by ID and testing for category membership?

Comment: I have my main subcategory from where I start and then I look for most similar data fields. I thought of getting 1 subcategory, loop through data in Node.js and afterwards erase best (most similar) fields from redis.

Comment: You should probably update your question with the details of your use-case. There are lots of ways to represent categorized data.

Comment: But the diagram is a great beginning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this.
One is to store hashsets with names concatenating

```
"category:subcategory:data" -> key1: value1, key2: value2, ...
```

Through this you can fetch your information if you know what you are looking for.
If searching is your issue then you'll need to add more calls to the redis server which will have a performance impact. But it all depends on how you want to search that data.

As meta information, you can create separate hashsets to facilitate not loosing an data.

```
List of categories
Hashset of categories -> SubCategories
categories:subcategories -> 4data points
categories:subcategories:data -> keys and values.
```

Comment: If you meant searching is my issue, I can easily do "HGETALL 1:1", it fits my needs. I added one more category, so now HGETALL would be followed by "1:1:1". In 1:n:m I have n = 240, m = 18 therefore I create n*m = 4320 keys - each still have O(1) access time, thus only bottleneck would be HGETALL which have O(n) - taking into account that there not so many elements inside one x:y:z, it's going to be pretty fast, am I right?

Comment: Yes hgetall on x:y:z is O(4) since you have 4 fields attached to it

Comment: therfore yeah its going to be hell lot of faster than hgetall on all of the keys